# Maximum Size .cab Visual Studio 2012 - InstallShield

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, installshield, cab

I need help.

I developed an application C# Visual Studio 2012, and now I'm trying to create the installer, I use InstallShield Limited Edition.

But I have a problem: I add an Application File that size is 2.5 GB and when I compile the project then VS show this error:

Error   14  -7108: %s is too large to store in a .cab (2 GB maximum).   ISEXP : error : -7108: %s is too large to store in a .cab (2 GB maximum)

I need to know if exists any way to resolve this or if exists other tool to create Installers that support files that size is up 2 GB

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of the CAB file format. See here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2005/09/18/461810.aspx

The only workaround as far as I can see:

> You can avoid these limits by splitting your setup into multiple CABs, possibly up to 64K * 2GB, or by placing your application files on the distribution disk uncompressed.

Source: http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1043.htm